# From where this 2 came in output? Fibonacci series using python Lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, while-loop, fibonacci

**If you do not want to read this text, I have explained the problem in this Youtube video:** https://youtu.be/Ekkkgjf0F_s

Following is the code that I am using to generate **Fibonacci series using python 
lists.**

```
list1 = [0, 1]
x=1
while x <=2:
    length = len(list1)
    first =list1[length-2]
    second =list1[length-1]
    third = first + second
    list1.append(third)
    x+=1
    print list1
```

When the while loop runs for the 1st iteration, it generates the upcoming element in series and stores in list exactly what it should do. 
The list will now become:

```
list1 = [0,1,1]
```

But what confusing me is when the second iteration is made by while loop. 
If you dry run the code, you will see that the code is outputting 2 (according to fibonacci series sequence, it is right)
but **if we dry run the code, the 4th element should be 3 instead of 2**

2nd interation, length = 3>>**Dry RUN below**:

```
 3-2=1
    3-1=2
    1+2=3
    list1 should be: [0,1,1,3]
```

But i am getting the output as:
      **`list1=[0,1,1,2]`**

I can't understand , how this 2 came in output.

Comment: Umm, the Fibonacci series goes as; 0, 1, 1, **2**, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your list has `len()` of 3, and therefore your algorithm adds element 1 and 2 (which are both 1) together. that's why you get returned the 2.

EDIT: which is exactly how the Fibonacci-Series goes....

Code with comments as follows:

```
length = len(list1)       #3
first =list1[length-2]    #list on index 1 is value 1
second =list1[length-1]   #list on index 2 is value 1
third = first + second    # 1+1 = 2
list1.append(third)       # 2 is appended
x+=1
print list1
```

you probably confuse the value on list index [1] with the actual difference between len of list 3 and 1.

Comment: Oh my god. Thanks so much :)

Answer (score 1):

When you list1 becomes `[0,1,1]`, the len of list1 is 3.

Now try running the following:

```
length = len(list1) = 3
first = list1[length-2] = list1[3-2] = list1[1] = 1
second = list1[length-1] = list1[3-1] = list1[2] = 1
third = first + second = 1 + 1 = 2
```

Hence, it adds 2 to the list.